# Cocos2D 2.0 - converting boundingBox coordinates to director view space

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need to show a UIActionSheet on a popover and this popover has an arrow pointing to an element on Cocos2D.

I need to calculate this element's boundingBox rect in terms of the director view coordinates where the UIActionSheet will be shown, so the action sheet arrow will be pointing to it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick sample I created, Just change the UIPopoverController to your UIActionSheet.

```
CCNode* node = (CCNode *)sender;
CGPoint worldPoint = [node convertToWorldSpace:CGPointZero];
CGRect rect = [sender boundingBox];
rect.origin = worldPoint;
// Convert position based on Apple's anchor point from cocos2d's anchor point
rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y + rect.size.height;
CGPoint convertedLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToUI:ccp(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y)];
rect.origin = convertedLocation;

UIViewController* viewController= [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[viewController view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
UIPopoverController* c = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
[c presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Nope. This is not giving me the right coordinates. The X seems to be more or less right, but the Y is completely wrong.

Comment: note: this sprite is inside another sprite that is inside a layer... does this makes any difference?

Comment: yeah, it matters, the bounding box returns different coordinate, try this on the sprite that in main layer. see if it's correct

Comment: nope. Not working for sprites on the main layer too. What's the point of this ConverToUI if it is unable to follow the sprite hierarchy? The equivalent UIKit function to convert rects work like a charm for any view in any hierarchy.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh now it is working!!!!!  care to explain the code? I always want to know why, so next time I will not bother people asking!   thanks.

Comment: Yeah, basically, you present your UIActionSheet inside your openGLView, so you have to convert your sprite position (which is relative to parent) to the openGLView, ([node convertToWorldSpace:CGPointZero];), then boundingBox rect (0,0 bottom left), to match the one that UIKit use (0,0 top left). (rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y + rect.size.height;) and finally, convert position to UIKit position (CGPoint convertedLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToUI:ccp(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y)];
rect.origin = convertedLocation;)